# connection between opencart and mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, opencart

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/3118): Access denied for user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'. Account is locked. in C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: mysqli object is already closed in C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php:10 Stack trace: #0 

C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\install\controller\install\step_3.php(274): DB\MySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'mysql.infoschem...', 'Salah509', 'opencart', '3306') #1

C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\install\controller\install\step_3.php(8): ControllerInstallStep3->validate() #2

C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\engine\action.php(79): ControllerInstallStep3->index() #3 C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\engine\router.php(67): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #4 C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\engine\router.php(56): Router->execute(Object(Action)) #5

C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\framework.php(165): Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) #6 

C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\startup.php(104): require_once('C:\\Server\\data\\...') #7 C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\install\index.php(37): start('install') #8 {main} thrown in C:\Server\data\htdocs\opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 10
```

I just Installed `Apache 2.4.46, PHP 8.0.1, mysql 8.0.22` and `phpmyadmin 5.0.4`, when i start install `opencat 3.0.6` and connect the db i got this long error how i can fix it please
thanks

Comment: I just realized a user named mysql.infoschema in all my dbs  with non Grant Administration permeation does it can be the wrong  –

Comment: This seems like being of administrative nature rather than programming (see the [tag:opencart] tag description about alternative places. If it _is_ programming related, it lacks steps to reproduce and code that you've tried. Check [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I resolve it using by Change the lines of code from the following files:

install/cli_install.php

Search for $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'"); and replace with $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''");

install/model/install/install.php

Search for $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'"); and replace with $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''");

Comment: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=218433 -----------------------------------------------------------In Arabic language

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines of code from the following files:

install/cli_install.php
Search for

$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'"); and replace with $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''");

install/model/install/install.php

Search for

$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'"); and replace with $db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''"); –

In Arabic its here

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=218433